# How to make a struct with `variable: [String: Codable]` codable?

Tags: swift, codable

I got a struct like the following

```
struct Wrapper {

  var value: [String: Any]
  // type "Any" could be String, Int or [String]. 
  // i.g. ["a": 1, "b": ["ccc"]]
  // and the keys of this dictionary are not determined 
}
```

I been struggled for quite a while.
Anyone has any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: You can use enum types instead of Any but i think such missy json need a usual serialization not codable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use some library like [AnyCodable](https://github.com/Flight-School/AnyCodable)

Then you can make your struct Codable by using AnyCodable class instead of Any.

```
struct Wrapper: Codable {
    var value: [String: AnyCodable]
}
```

Example

```
let arrayWrapper: [String: Any] =
["value" :
       [
         "test" : ["1", "2", "3"],
         "parse" : ["4", "5", "6"]]
        ]

let jsonData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arrayWrapper, options: .prettyPrinted)

do {
   let decoder = JSONDecoder()
   let result = try decoder.decode(Wrapper.self, from: jsonData)
   print("result:", result)
} catch let error {
   print("error:", error)
}
```

Output

```
result: Wrapper(value: ["parse": AnyCodable(["4", "5", "6"]), "test": AnyCodable(["1", "2", "3"])])
```